Rayleigh Quotient and Maximum and Minimum Eigenvalues
I'm just starting my linear algebra course at university, and I came across the following exercise:
Consider the matrix
 of size
4×4:

A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
4 & 2 & 1 & 3 \\
5 & 1 & 60 & 12 \\
1 & 3 & 12 & 48
\end{bmatrix}

​
The exercise asks me to:
a)Show that the largest eigenvalue of matrix
 is greater than 67.4.
b)Show that the smallest eigenvalue of
 is less than -2.1.
I’ve looked into the Rayleigh quotient, but I'm not entirely sure if that's the correct approach to solve this. The exercise suggests using the characterization of eigenvalues by maximums and minimums, but I'm not quite sure how to apply that in this context.
Could someone guide me on how to use this characterization or suggest an alternative method to solve it? I’d appreciate any help or detailed explanation you could offer!
Thank you in advance.

I think the question setter simply wants you to solve the characteristic equation of directly.
